# expression is of wrong type for function

Tags: plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION k_w_b_salary(k IN NUMBER, b IN BOOLEAN)
RETURN EMP.ENAME%TYPE IS 

names name_table;

BEGIN
IF (b = true) THEN
    SELECT ENAME BULK COLLECT INTO names
    FROM 
    (SELECT *
    FROM EMP
    ORDER BY SAL ASC)
    WHERE ROWNUM <= k;
    RETURN names;
ELSIF (b = false) THEN
    SELECT ENAME BULK COLLECT INTO names
    FROM
    (SELECT *
    FROM EMP
    ORDER BY SAL DESC)
    WHERE ROWNUM <= k;
    RETURN names;
END IF;
END;
```

And I get this error:
12/9      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
12/16     PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
20/9      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
20/16     PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

I have this function that tries to find the best/worst paid employees. But i get the above error.
I think it's something to do with the ROWNUM but I am not sure.
I think the lines the error points out are not the lines with the error.
I had this function writen differently and the lines in the error where pointing to the ROWNUM <= k lines.
I have tried putting a fixed number there (<= 3) for example and I got the same error.
I have no idea what else to try, i can't really understand why this is not working.
It's not obvious to me why this is not working. I think it should work fine but obviously it dousen't.
The code for the table i use is :
`CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE name_table IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10);`
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What should happen if the input argument **b** is NULL? Your function will not return anything in that case (which means it will throw an error, as functions **must** return something). Also - do you plan to use this function in SQL, or only in PL/SQL? If you want to be able to call it in SQL, you will need to use a different data type for **b**, since Oracle SQL (unlike PL/SQL) does not support BOOLEAN.

Comment: By the way, `IF (b = true) THEN` can be written more simply as `if b then`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function declaration, you said

```
RETURN EMP.ENAME%TYPE
```

I assume the data type of column ENAME in table EMP is some sort of string (VARCHAR2(40) or similar) - right?

In the declarations section, you declare a variable `names` of data type `name_table`. You didn't show us the definition of the `name_table` type (that **must** be given outside the function, not in it); we can probably assume it is a nested table of some sort. Right? [**EDIT** - I take that back; you did show us your definition of `name_table`, at the end of your question.]

In the end, your function returns `names`. Which is of type `name_table`. But you said the function returns something else: `EMP.ENAME%TYPE`. In particular, you said the function returns a scalar data type, but you are returning a collection.

This will not work **even if the collection has a single element**. A table with a single "record" is not the same data type as the "record" itself - even if an actual table has a single "record" in it.

(And, much more so, when the table has three records in it!)

Rather: It seems that you want a **table** function: one that returns a table of things. If so, then declare the function that way. Perhaps you want the function to

```
RETURN NAME_TABLE
```

(at the top, in the function declaration)

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I show the definition of the name_table after the main block of code, almost the last thing I say. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ΗλίαςΚαλερίδης - Yep, I see it now. I edited the answer to clarify.